# TeamCity and running NUnit tests

Tags: nunit, teamcity

In TeamCity, i need to state exact locations of assemblies that contain NUnit tests to be executed.

Is there an option to state a .SLN file so it will look up these test projects dynamically?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use wildcard expressions in the **Run tests from** box:

```
Source\\**\bin\\**\*Tests.dll
```

The above would run tests from any assembly under any bin folder under the Source folder which contains 'Tests' at the end of the assembly name.

Comment: Thanks, awesomely helpful. I adapted this slightly to include the build configuration: `%system.teamcity.build.workingDir%\\**\bin\%env.BUILD_CONFIG%\\**\*Tests.dll`

Comment: exact path of the dll can be given too.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whether you're using MSBuild or NAnt, you can add an entry to your build script like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <TestAssemblies Include="tests\\test*.dll"/>
  <TestAssemblies Include="tests.lib\\test*.dll"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="runTests">
  <Exec Command="$(teamcity_dotnet_nunitlauncher) v2.0 x86 NUnit-2.5.0 %(TestAssemblies)" />
</Target>
```

In the example above, the two TestAssemblies lines point to your assemblies.

You can read more about this here: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2008/09/24/using-teamcity-nunit-launcher/

Comment: Thanks, will consider this, if we switch to building using Msbuild! very helpful.